# way to copy data with new foreign key ids

Tags: sql, postgresql, scala, slick

In a multi tenant system say there is a base tenant say it's tenantId =1 which has a set of tables populated with tenant 1 data in it. every time new tenant is created system first copies data from base tenant into new tenant (the one being created). Say new tenant id =2.

Tenant Id =1 has tables like say

```
ROLE
id   | name      | tenant_id
1    | AdminRole | 1
```

say every tenant gets "AdminRole" out of the box - AND later they may change it's name, from out of the box provided name - "AdminRole" to "Administrator" - reason why roles are specific to tenants. This role table is just an example there are other such cases when copying base tenant into a new tenant. when new tenant is created role table first will look like below

```
ROLE 
id  | name          |tenant_id
1   | AdminRole     | 1
2   | AdminRole     | 2
```

once tenant 2 is successfully created tenant 2 may change to "Administrator"

```
ROLE 
id  | name            |tenant_id
1   | AdminRole       | 1
2   | Administrator   | 2
```

this is NOT a lookup table with static data. these data are NOT tenant agnostic

now there are other tables which refers to roles as Foreign key. data for tenant_id =1 will have right role_id (=1) being referred because that data already existed.

Now for tenant_id =2 - system will have to know how to link data in other tables which refers to role table (as FK) to role_id=2. Unless I maintain some type of Map of (role_id in tenant 1 -> role_id in tenant 2) I don't have a way to get role_id=2 to use into new data being copied for tenant 2.

for e.g. when data from tenant 1 is copied and if role_id is being referred I'll have to know what new role_id is for tenant 2.

```
val roleMap = Map(1 -> 2) //1= role_id from tenant 1, 2= role_id from tenant 2

and then every time role_id is being referred while copying tenant 1 data into tenant 2 , it lookup what new role id it should put into tenant 2 data. this approach doesn't look like a best way to deal with this situation. All this is being done at an application level not DB level. What are better ways to deal with this?
```

p.s. there isn't anything Scala specific in the question but reason to tag Scala is to see if there is neat way using language/other trickery ways to deal with this since solution is at an application level not at a db level.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should add the keys you are loking for as an extra row in the table.

```
 id |     name      | key | tenant_id 
----+---------------+-----+-----------
  1 | AdminRole     |   1 |         1
  2 | Administrator |   1 |         2
```

In your Allplication map the key of the Role and not the id.
So for every tenant the key of the Admin-Role stays the same.